# java - subinterface overriding superinterfaces method

Tags: java, interface

I´m currently trying to write a game engine/library in java and have a problem while creating the event system. I want to have a global EventManager class to manage an event queue once per update. This class should not be changed by the user, but it should be able to work with event listeners and events, which the user created. So I have an abstract class Event from which the user can create subclasses as his own event types. The listeners, which the user creates should all be subinterfaces of the EventListener interface, so that the user can implement several of his own listeners into a class.
Since every listener has specific eventTypes that should trigger his action method, there must be a variable or method that can tell the EventManager which events are interesting for this listener.

Is there a way that the subinterfaces are able to override the method of the superinterface?
Or is there another good solution to the problem of matching the listeners to events?

Here are the parts of the classes and interfaces I made until now:

The EventManager class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EventManager {

private static ArrayList<Event> eventQueue = new ArrayList<Event>();
private static ArrayList<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<EventListener>();

public static void queueEvent(Event e){
    eventQueue.add(e);
}

public static void instantEvent(Event e){
    for(int i = 0; i < eventQueue.size(); i++){
        for(int l = 0; l < listeners.size(); l ++){
            if(listeners.get(l).getEventTypes().contains(e))listeners.get(l).trigger(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void processEventQueue(){
    for(int i = 0; i < eventQueue.size(); i++){
        for(int l = 0; l < listeners.size(); l ++){
            if(listeners.get(l).getEventTypes().contains(eventQueue.get(i)))listeners.get(l).trigger(eventQueue.get(i));
        }
    }
    eventQueue.clear();
}

public static void addListener(Object o){
    if(o instanceof EventListener)listeners.add((EventListener) o);
}

public static void removeListener(Object o){
    if(o instanceof EventListener)listeners.remove((EventListener) o);
}
```

}

abstract Event superclass:

```
public abstract class Event {
//Just empty, maybe I´ll put in something later...
}
```

EventListener superinterface:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract interface EventListener{

public abstract void trigger(Event e);

public abstract ArrayList<Event> getEventTypes();
}
```

Listener subinterface:

```
public interface ExampleListener extends EventListener{

@Override
public ArrayList<Event> getEventTypes(){
    //This method isn´t allowed to have a body.
            //----THAT IS THE PROBLEM----
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Methods in interfaces are per definition abstract. If you want to have a method implemented in the hierarchy like that, perhaps consider abstract classes instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an interface extends another interface, like in a class it inherits all it's methods.

I understand your problem and I've had it before.
You are not allowed to have any implementation on interfaces. You could choose to make it into an abstract class, but then you may need to extend multiple classes, which you can't.
What you may want to do is keep a reference of the abstract class (which implements that interface), instead, and just use that reference for event related things.
You could also save yourself by just having it in an anonymous way:

```
EventListener evListener = new EventListener(){
  void trigger(Event e){
    //do whatever with event e
  }

  ArrayList<Event> getEventTypes(){
    //return event type
  }
};
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution in the codeblock , i will try to do it that way :) . But you described two solutions and i dont anderstand the other one. Could you give me an example for that?

Comment: ok. The solution on the code block means that you are initializing an object of the EventListener type and defining it at runtime. The other solution, which would actually have the same effect is:

public class ExampleEvent implements EventListener{
   public void trigger(Event e){
     //... trigger implementation
   }

  public ArrayList<Event> getEventTypes(){
    //.... getEventTypes implementation
  }
}

this class can now have all the implementation that your interface itself can't!
now you can have a reference to ExampleEvent (which has implementation)!
got it?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are only like contracts, they assure that the class will define the methods given in the interface. The main purpose of interfaces are that, if you know a class implements an interface, then you also know you will find the methods of the interface in the class.

More readable, and supports the naming conventions.

Try using abstract classes instead for this.

Comment: The  thing is that a class can only inherit from one superclass, but from several interfaces ... right? I want to have the  possibility to have more  than one listener or  a superclass plus a listener.

Comment: Yes but don't try to exchange superclass and interfaces.. Interface is just a set of methods that MUST BE DEFINED in the class the interface is implemented in. I don't really understand your exact problem, can you please give me more exact informations about how do you plan to make the class tree, what would you like to achive?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the java 8 default methods:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html